# How to view plot in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

Repro

```
In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/prophet/main/examples/example_pedestr
   ...: ians_covid.csv')
   ...:

In [3]: df.set_index('ds').plot();
   ...:
```

But this isn't plotting anything? How do I view the plot?

Following docs here: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/handling_shocks.html#treating-covid-19-lockdowns-as-a-one-off-holidays

Comment: remove the ';' at the end your plot statement and try again.

Comment: plt.show() after importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt